# How do I export save games in (browser based) Cragne Manor

Tags: cragne-manor

I play in browser, but I use sometimes laptop and sometimes desktop. How do I export or backup my progress?

Game is here
https://rcveeder.net/cragne/play.html

Comment: Here's what I've figured out so far: You can export a save file by clicking "Edit" in the save/restore dialog box and then "displaying" and saving the file. To load that file on another machine, it supposedly should go somewhere in your browser's Local Storage directory, but I haven't been able to figure out how. People at the intfiction.org forum may be able to help more (the Quixe developer posts there quite a lot).